# Laravel login - use of autofocus

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I need to extend my login form so that the autofocus is sent to the field where the validation has failed.

So, if the username is incorrect, the username field should clear, and have the focus sent to it.

Conversely, if the password fails, the focus should be sent to the password field.

I could do this in php for sure, but unsure how to adapt Laravel's native form elements to accomplish this.

```
 <form method="post" autocomplete="off" role="form">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{{ csrf_token() }}}" />
    <div class="form-group @if($errors->has('username')) has-error @endif">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        {{ Form::text('username', null, array('placeholder' => 'Username', 'autofocus' => 'true', 'id' => 'username', 'class' => 'form-control required')) }}
        @if($errors->has('username')) <p class="help-block">{{{ $errors->first('username') }}}</p>@endif
    </div>
    <div class="form-group @if($errors->has('password')) has-error @endif">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        {{ Form::password('password', array('placeholder' => 'Password', 'id' => 'password', 'class' => 'form-control required')) }}
        @if($errors->has('password')) <p class="help-block">{{{ $errors->first('password') }}}</p>@endif
    </div>
    {{ Form::submit('Login', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'title' => 'Login')) }}
</form>
```

Comment: autofocus is not laravels work, this is for html and javascript ;)

Comment: @MaximilianPrepl I would say that, while you could do it with JavaScript only, @Suba's question is how to make a field focused `after` the failed submission. So this is a server-side validation question and it may concern Laravel as well.

Comment: Suba while this is probably possible to create, I'm not sure if it's considered to be a good practice. What would you do in case when both username and password are incorrect? I would personally prefer to have old input passed to the form (without password, of course), and add error notifications which would lead a user to correct them.

Comment: @ТомицаКораћ, no that's not server side, because if you have errors, with validator, you need to make it visible. so if you make it visible, you can get where ;)

Comment: @ТомицаКораћ http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#error-messages-and-views

Comment: @MaximilianPrepl not sure I understand you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what I will do in javascript at the Blade's View Section.
I yield a section called 'scripts' on my template.

I'm using with Jquery Plugin to select element.

```
@section('scripts')

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

  @if($errors->first('user'))
    $("input[name='username']").focus();
  @elseif($errors->first('password'))
    $("input[name='password']").focus();
  @endif

});

</script>

@stop
```

Comment: This is a much better alternative to my answer (and I completely forgot to mention that JS would be better, d'oh).

Comment: This is a great alternative.  Thank you so much for your contribution

Answer (score 2):

I think the main problem is that you won't be able to do this with Laravel's native form helpers and have it just work. You *could* extend the FormBuilder class and add in your own logic (that accepts the validator/errors bag on instantiation and automatically appends `autofocus` to the first form input it outputs that has an error) but I think your best bet would just be to do this in the view with some ifs (or maybe use a presenter to save on all the view logic).

In a view:

```
{{ Form::open(['autocomplete' => 'off', 'role' => 'form']) }}
    <div class="form-group @if ($errors->has('username')) has-error @endif">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <?php $attrs = ['placeholder' => 'Username', 'id' => 'username', 'class' => 'form-control required'];
        @if ($errors->has('username'))
            <?php $attrs[] = 'autofocus'; ?>
        @endif
        {{ Form::text('username', null, $attrs) }}
        @if ($errors->has('username'))
            <p class="help-block">{{{ $errors->first('username') }}}</p>
        @endif
    </div>
    <div class="form-group @if($errors->has('password')) has-error @endif">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <?php $attrs = ['placeholder' => 'Password', 'id' => 'password', 'class' => 'form-control required'];
        @if ($errors->has('password') && (! $errors->has('username')))
            <?php $attrs[] = 'autofocus'; ?>
        @endif
        {{ Form::password('password', $attrs) }}
        @if ($errors->has('password'))
            <p class="help-block">{{{ $errors->first('password') }}}</p>
        @endif
    </div>

    {{ Form::submit('Login', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'title' => 'Login')) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

It's not pretty, having to put PHP code in there in order to dynamically add the attributes, which you could maybe change with a ternary:

```
{{ Form::password(
    'password',
    [
        'placeholder' => 'Password',
        'id'          => 'password',
        'class'       => 'form-control required',
        'autofocus'   => ($errors->has('password') && (! $errors->has('username')) ? 'autofocus' : null)
    ]
) }}
```

But that's still not great obviously.

But yeah, extending the FormBuilder class seems like even more effort - I guess it depends on how many of these types of form you plan on using in your application and how many fields you have to deal with (as the in-view method above get increasingly complicated with more fields as you have to add in all the `! $errors->has('prev_field')` bits).